# How to use Databinding?

Tags: android-databinding, model-binding

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxmAJ.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxn7k.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNyBJ.jpg)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6E0z.jpg)
`I tried to learn a lot through videos but failed. I want you to help me I tried to learn a lot through videos but failed. I want you to help me I have been researching for many days and to no avail.Thank everybody so much`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask